# Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

A issue in the `this.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);`the web3.js has output and I type to the code of `console.log(window.web3.currentProvider)`that `window.web3.currentProvider is defined`. But the terminal occurs issue like as fellow:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.service.ts(36,20): error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

[image]

I import the web3.js like that :`enter preformatted text here`

Comment: I import the web3.js like that : import * as Web3 from 'web3';

Comment: Environment:
system:Ubuntu16.04
web.js:"1.0.0-beta.33"

Comment: Any news on that? Got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this by changing import to
`import Web3 from 'web3';`

Hope it helps